# A real matrix whose eigenvalues have all negative real parts

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

While taking a look in some lecture notes of an ODE course, I found the following claim, which appeared in the text as an exercise:

Let $A$ be a real $n\times n$ matrix whose eigenvalues have all negative real parts. Then there is some $\beta>0$ such that $$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n\quad\langle Ax,x\rangle\leq-\beta\|x\|^2.$$I think the claim is *false*, as can be shown by taking for example $$A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&-1\\1&-1\end{array}\right).$$The characteristic polynomial is $$f_A(x)=\left|\begin{array}{rr}x&1\\-1&x+1\end{array}\right|=x^2+x+1,$$and its roots are $$x=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{-3}}{2},$$so the real parts are negative. But taking $x=(1,0),$ $$\langle Ax,x\rangle=\langle(0,1),(1,0)\rangle=0,$$which shows that the above claim does not hold.

**My problem:** This claim is used in the text to prove a theorem which seems to be well-known and important. I guess the proof is not totally wrong, therefore I suspect that the above claim can be modified and turn into a true one. This is the point where I'll be happy to hear any suggestions.

**Some ODE intuition:** Consider the linear equation $$\frac{dy}{dt}=Ay.$$ Any solution is of the form $$y(t)=e^{tA}y_0,$$and if $A$'s eigenvalues all have negative real parts, it turns out that all the solutions get closer to $0$ as $t\to\infty$. The above (false) claim says that $\|y\|$ is decreasing at any time in this case. It could be nice to state a condition that can actually guarantee that.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What exactly says the theorem?

Comment: Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be twice differentiable with $f(0)=0$, and consider the equation $y'=f(y)$. Suppose that all the eigenvalues of $Df(0)$ have negative real parts. Then the trivial solution $y\equiv0$ is asymptotically stable.

Comment: I don't know about the ODE part but as a linear algebra claim it is false - actually your method shows any non invariable matrix with eigenvalues with negative real parts can be an example

Comment: "$0$ is asymptotically stable" means solutions sufficiently close to $0$ go to $0$ as $t \to \infty$.  They don't have to go monotonically to $0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael But the theorem regards a general vector field, that needs not be linear. The proof in my text shows linear stability first, and then uses it with the claim to deduce asymptotic stability.   You know what, if you happen to know a good reference which I can use to find a satisfactory proof of the theorem, I'll be to know about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The condition for $\|y\|$ to be (strictly) decreasing for all $y_0 \ne 0$, where 
$y = \exp(At) y_0$, is that $A + A^T$ is negative definite.  If $A + A^T$ is negative semidefinite (as in your example), $\|y\|$ will be nonincreasing.
But you can also have cases where all eigenvalues of $A$ are negative and 
$A + A^T$ is indefinite, e.g. $$A = \pmatrix{1 & 3\cr -3 & -4\cr}$$
and then $\|y\|$ will not be decreasing.

However, it is still true that $\|\exp(tA) y_0\| \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$ whenever all eigenvalues of $A$ have negative real parts.  In fact, using Jordan canonical
form, we can write  $\exp(t A) = \sum_j P_j(t) \exp(-\lambda_j t)$ where $P_j(t)$ are matrices
whose entries are polynomials in $t$.  If all $\text{Re}(\lambda_j) < 0$,
this implies that all entries of $\exp(tA)$ go to $0$ as $t \to \infty$.

If you don't want to use Jordan canonical form, you can also obtain  $\exp(t A) = \sum_j P_j(t) \exp(-\lambda_j t)$ from a Laplace transform.  Let 
$$G(s) = \int_0^\infty \exp(-st) \exp(tA)\; ds
= \int_0^\infty \exp(t(A-sI))\; dt$$ be the Laplace transform of
$\exp(tA)$ (i.e. the matrix whose entries are the Laplace transforms of the 
entries of $\exp(tA)$).  For $\text{Re}(s)$ sufficiently large, the improper integral converges, since $\|\exp(tA)\| \le \exp(t\|A\|)$ for $t \ge 0$.
  Note that $$A G(s) = \int_0^\infty \exp(-st) A \exp(-tA)\; dt = \int_0^\infty \exp(-st) \dfrac{d}{dt} \exp(tA)\; dt
$$
and using integration by parts (for $s$ large enough) this is
$$ I + s \int_0^\infty \exp(-st) \exp(tA)\; dt = I + s G(s) $$
Thus $(A - s I) G(s) = I$, or $$G(s) = (A - s I)^{-1}$$
The entries of $(A - s I)^{-1}$ are rational functions of $s$ with poles at the eigenvalues $\lambda_j$ of $A$ (obtainable from Cramer's Rule), and go to $0$ as $s \to \infty$.  Expand this in 
partial fractions: 
$$G(s) = \sum_j \sum_{k=1}^{n_j} \dfrac{R_{jk}}{(s - \lambda_j)^{k}}$$
for some matrices $R_{jk}$ and positive integers $n_j$.  Now take the inverse Laplace transform.